# Как раскрасить .png картинку градиентом?

Tags: css, css3, svg, linear-gradient

Есть такая вот картинка:
[image: Holo Img]

Мне нужно как-то наложить поверх неё градиент, чтобы он повторял контуры изображения (в дальнейшем собираюсь менять `background-position` градиента при движении мышкой, чтобы она красиво переливалась, как голографические марки).

Нашёл только для текста:

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Есть что-то подобное для `.png` картинок? А для `.svg`?

Comment: Наверное наличие альфа канала как то влияет, не?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду, но думаю да, т.к. прозрачный фон - это прозрачный фон.

Comment: в svg делайте..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Решение SVG

1. С помощью SVG маски, в состав которой включено `*.png` изображение лепестков, вырезаем контур лепестков из основы, к которой будет применена маска
2. Заполняем контуры линейным градиентом

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" >
      <g fill="white">
       <image filter="url(#monochrome)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVIRY.png" width="100%" height="100%" style="" />
      </g>
    </mask> 
    <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="green" /> 
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
     <filter id="monochrome"  color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="0 0 0 1 0
              0 0 0 1 0
              0 0 0 1 0
              1 0 0 0 0" />
  </filter>
 </defs>    
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Lg)" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

### Анимация градиента при наведении

Анимируем атрибуты линейного градиента `y2` или `x2` или оба вместе

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" >
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
      <g filter="url(#monochrome)">
       <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVIRY.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
      </g>
    </mask> 
    <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
          
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="green"/>
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="yellow"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="red"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" begin="svg1.mouseenter" values="1;0.5;1" dur="1.5s"  />
          <animate attributeName="x2" begin="svg1.mouseenter" values="0.1;1;0.1" dur="1.5s"  />
      </linearGradient> 
       <filter id="monochrome"  color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="0 0 0 1 0
              0 0 0 1 0
              0 0 0 1 0
              1 0 0 0 0" />
  </filter>
  </defs>
    
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Lg)" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

*Вращение цветной полосы градиента*

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" >
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
      <g fill="white">
       <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVIRY.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
      </g>
    </mask> 
    <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" begin="svg1.mouseenter" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s"  />
        <animate attributeName="y1" begin="svg1.mouseenter" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s"  />
        <animate attributeName="x2" begin="svg1.mouseenter" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s"  />
        <animate attributeName="y2" begin="svg1.mouseenter" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s"  />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#Lg)" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Хорошое решение, правда, немного громоздское. В любом случае с меня лайк

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) на блок, а анимацию градиента сделать при помощи псевдоэлемента и там уже вращать как угодно.

Правда беда с [поддержкой](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image) `mask-image`.

```css
body {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 100%; min-height: 100vh; background: #222; margin: 0;}

.gradient-mask {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-mask-image: url('//i.imgur.com/rjLTNCv.png');
          mask-image: url('//i.imgur.com/rjLTNCv.png');
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
          mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
          mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-size: 80% auto;
          mask-size: 80% auto;
  position: relative;
}

.gradient-mask::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red 25%, orange, lime, green 75%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform .3s linear;
}

.gradient-mask:hover::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-mask"></div>
```

Comment: Да, я тоже это нашёл. Спасибо за ответ, но хотелось бы посмотреть и на другие варианты (если таковые имеются). В любом случае, с меня лайк

Comment: Спасибо, но думаю лучший только на SVG